# Creating a Time to Treatment Variable

Tags: r, panel, lubridate, datediff

Rewording question and adding a toy data frame.

I am trying to create a time to treatment variable for a panel dataframe at the district level. The dataframe is constructed with time observed quarterly. The time to treatment variable should show the number of quarters prior to treatment as a negative number (...,-3, -2,-1), quarter of treatment as 0, and number of quarters post treatment (1, 2, 3, ...) for each district/quarter observation. Sample dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(District = c("Afgooye", "Afgooye", "Afgooye", "Afgooye", "Afgooye", "Afgooye", "Afgooye", "Afgooye",
                                  "Balcad", "Balcad", "Balcad", "Balcad", "Balcad", "Balcad", "Balcad", "Balcad"), 
                     YearQuarter = as.yearqtr(c("2011 Q1", "2011 Q2", "2011 Q3", "2011 Q4", "2012 Q1", "2012 Q2", "2012 Q3", "2012 Q4",
                                                "2011 Q1", "2011 Q2", "2011 Q3", "2011 Q4", "2012 Q1", "2012 Q2", "2012 Q3", "2012 Q4")),
                     date = as_date(c("2011-01-01", "2011-04-02", "2011-07-01", "2011-10-01", "2012-01-01", "2012-04-01", "2012-07-01", "2012-10-01",
                              "2011-01-01", "2011-04-02", "2011-07-01", "2011-10-01", "2012-01-01", "2012-04-01", "2012-07-01", "2012-10-01")), 
                     conflict = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
                     timetreatment = c(0,  0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), 
                basepresent = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)), class = "data.frame", 
                 row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

timetreatment is variable equal to 1 the quarter that treatment of district began and 0 otherwise.

What I want is reflected in variable timetotreatment is presented in this second toy data frame.

```
df1 <- structure(list(District = c("Afgooye", "Afgooye", "Afgooye", "Afgooye", "Afgooye", "Afgooye", "Afgooye", "Afgooye",
                                  "Balcad", "Balcad", "Balcad", "Balcad", "Balcad", "Balcad", "Balcad", "Balcad"), 
                     YearQuarter = as.yearqtr(c("2011 Q1", "2011 Q2", "2011 Q3", "2011 Q4", "2012 Q1", "2012 Q2", "2012 Q3", "2012 Q4",
                                                "2011 Q1", "2011 Q2", "2011 Q3", "2011 Q4", "2012 Q1", "2012 Q2", "2012 Q3", "2012 Q4")),
                     date = as_date(c("2011-01-01", "2011-04-02", "2011-07-01", "2011-10-01", "2012-01-01", "2012-04-01", "2012-07-01", "2012-10-01",
                              "2011-01-01", "2011-04-02", "2011-07-01", "2011-10-01", "2012-01-01", "2012-04-01", "2012-07-01", "2012-10-01")), 
                     conflict = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
                     timetreatment = c(0,  0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), 
                     basepresent = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1),
                     timetotreat = c(-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3)), class = "data.frame", 
                row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Current code for desired transformation to create timetotreatment variable is

```
df <- df%>% mutate(timetotreatment = YearQuarter - YearQuarter[timetreatment == 1])

df <- df%>% mutate(timetotreatment = date - date[timetreatment == 1])
```

Both return values that are off, ie Quarter where timetreatment = 0 is not
returning timetotreatment=0.

```
> dput(head(df, 20))
structure(list(District = c("Afgooye", "Afgooye", "Afgooye", 
"Afgooye", "Afgooye", "Afgooye", "Afgooye", "Afgooye", "Balcad", 
"Balcad", "Balcad", "Balcad", "Balcad", "Balcad", "Balcad", "Balcad"
), YearQuarter = structure(c(2011, 2011.25, 2011.5, 2011.75, 
2012, 2012.25, 2012.5, 2012.75, 2011, 2011.25, 2011.5, 2011.75, 
2012, 2012.25, 2012.5, 2012.75), class = "yearqtr"), date = structure(c(14975, 
15066, 15156, 15248, 15340, 15431, 15522, 15614, 14975, 15066, 
15156, 15248, 15340, 15431, 15522, 15614), class = "Date"), conflict = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0), timetreatment = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), basepresent = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), timetotreatment = c(-0.75, 
-0.75, -0.25, -0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.75, 0.75, -0.75, -0.75, -0.25, 
-0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.75, 0.75), timetotreatment1 = structure(c(-273, 
-274, -92, -92, 92, 91, 274, 274, -273, -274, -92, -92, 92, 91, 
274, 274), class = "difftime", units = "days")), row.names = c(NA, 
16L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: To help in making this reproducible, could you share a sample of your data (editing your question with results of `dput(head(df, 20))`? Also it would be helpful to show for that sample data what the final/desired result should look like with `TimetoTreat`?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse`, and `data.table`'s run length id (rleid) function we can group by which segment an observation is in i.e `rleid==1` => pretreatment, `rleid==2` => treatment, `rleid==3` post-treatment :

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
 group_by(District) %>%
 mutate(t=data.table::rleid(timetreatment)) %>%
 group_by(t, .add=T) %>%
 mutate(timetotreat=- (t==1) * (n()+1) + row_number() - 1*(t==2)) %>%
 select(-t)
```

```
      t District YearQuarter date       conflict timetreatment basepresent timetotreat
   <int> <chr>    <yearqtr>   <date>        <dbl>         <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
 1     1 Afgooye  2011 Q1     2011-01-01        0             0           0          -3
 2     1 Afgooye  2011 Q2     2011-04-02        0             0           0          -2
 3     1 Afgooye  2011 Q3     2011-07-01        1             0           0          -1
 4     2 Afgooye  2011 Q4     2011-10-01        0             1           1           0
 5     3 Afgooye  2012 Q1     2012-01-01        0             0           1           1
 6     3 Afgooye  2012 Q2     2012-04-01        4             0           1           2
 7     3 Afgooye  2012 Q3     2012-07-01        0             0           1           3
 8     3 Afgooye  2012 Q4     2012-10-01        0             0           1           4
 9     1 Balcad   2011 Q1     2011-01-01        0             0           0          -4
10     1 Balcad   2011 Q2     2011-04-02        0             0           0          -3
11     1 Balcad   2011 Q3     2011-07-01        0             0           0          -2
12     1 Balcad   2011 Q4     2011-10-01        2             0           0          -1
13     2 Balcad   2012 Q1     2012-01-01        0             1           0           0
14     3 Balcad   2012 Q2     2012-04-01        0             0           1           1
15     3 Balcad   2012 Q3     2012-07-01        1             0           1           2
16     3 Balcad   2012 Q4     2012-10-01        0             0           1           3
```